# Prepending http:// to entries that don't have it

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many entries with different websites but some have http:// in front but some don't.

I would like to run some command that would add http:// in front of the ones that dont.

Example:

Before query:

```
example.com
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
cnn.com
```

After query:

```
http://example.com
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
http://cnn.com
```

Comment: OK. What exactly stops you?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i was able to do this writing a linux bash script that parsed a file of urls with a while command then setting the field to http://$i.
Not the best way but I got it done.
Thanks